# Bootstrap full-width column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, width

I have two columns one sidebar other one is page. How can I make the second column that it goes until the end of page? Why it end somewhere in the middle by default? first column had the same problem with height I tried d-block but didnt work then I wrote it in style.css height:100vh but for second column width:100vh didnt have the same effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Control Panel</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container m-0 p-0">
    <div class="row p-0">
      <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 d-block bg-secondary px-4 pt-2 bg-dark text-light">

        <div class="d-flex align-items-start flex-column px-2">
          <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand text-white"><h4>Admin<br>Panel</h4></a>

          <ul class="navbar-nav text-white">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="index.html" class="nav-link text-white active">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="tasks.html" class="nav-link text-white">Tasks</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="categories.html" class="nav-link text-white">Categories</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="users.html" class="nav-link text-white">Users</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="navbar-nav text-white mt-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i> User01
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a href="profile.html" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i> Profile</a>
                <a href="settings.html" class="dropdown-item"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Settings</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="login.html" class="nav-link text-white">
                <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout
              </a>
            </li>

          </ul>


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="page col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-8 p-0">
        <header id="main-header" class="py-2 bg-info text-white">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1><i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Dashboard</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>

        <section id="actions" class="py-4 mb-4 bg-light">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addTaskModal">
                  <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add Task
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-block" data-toggle="modal"
                  data-target="#addCategoryModal">
                  <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add Category
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addUserModal">
                  <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add User
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <!-- MODALS -->
        <!-- Task -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="addTaskModal">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                <h5 class="modal-title text-white">Add Task</h5>
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                  <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="category">Category</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                      <option value="1">Development</option>
                      <option value="2">Design</option>
                      <option value="3">Support</option>
                      <option value="4">Management</option>

                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="image">Upload Image</label>
                    <div class="custom-file">
                      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="image">
                      <label for="image" class="custom-file-label">Browse Image</label>
                    </div>
                    <small class="form-text text-muted">Max 3mb</small>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Task Description</label>
                    <textarea name="editor" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button class="btn bg-primary text-white">Submit</button>
                    <button class="btn bg-outline-primary text-white">Cancel</button>

                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Category -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="addCategoryModal">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header bg-warning">
                <h5 class="modal-title text-white">Add Category</h5>
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                  <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="category">Current Categories</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                      <option value="1">Development</option>
                      <option value="2">Design</option>
                      <option value="3">Support</option>
                      <option value="4">Management</option>

                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">New Category</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button class="btn bg-warning text-white">Submit</button>
                    <button class="btn bg-outline-warning text-white">Cancel</button>

                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <!-- User -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="addUserModal">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header bg-success">
                <h5 class="modal-title text-white">Add User</h5>
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                  <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password2">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="category">Category</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                      <option value="1">Moderator</option>
                      <option value="2">Editor</option>
                      <option value="3">Subscriber</option>
                      <option value="4">Ghost</option>

                    </select>
                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button class="btn bg-success text-white">Submit</button>
                    <button class="btn bg-outline-success text-white">Cancel</button>

                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.3/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

and the css

```
body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    padding:0;  
    margin:0;

}

.sidebar{
    height:100vh;
}
.page{
    width:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are relying on `.container` as your primary grid parent, but `.container` is a fixed-width class. Regardless of the custom CSS you write `.page` can never be greater than the width of `.container` which maxes out at 1140 pixels at the highest breakpoint that Bootstrap uses.

If you change your class to `.container-fluid` however it will *always* use `width:100%`.  That single change will result in the width of your container spanning the width of the browser viewport.

It's unclear if you also wanted your dark navigational menu to span 100% of the height, but that would require additional CSS declarations.  I highly recommend you review Bootstrap's documentation on its Grid system as well as its flex box utilities for managing sizing.

[Bootstrap 4.1.x Grid Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

[Bootstrap 4.1.x Flex Box Utility Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/)